# Does the anime adaptation of Absolute Duo deviate much from the light novel?

Tags: absolute-duo

From a quick scan through translated volumes of Absolute Duo on Baka Tsuki, it seems that the anime adapted up to Volume 5 - Chapter 2 (or a few more chapters ahead). However, looking at the illustrations, it seems that some content are not adapted in the anime.

What are the chapters missing from the anime adaptation? Within the adapted content, does the anime adaptation have any major deviation from the source material?